# Arduino stops working after being just minutes in use

Tags: arduino, android-keypad, keypad

When I run this code on my arduino nano for some reason after a while it seems to halt. I've tried booting it and waiting 5 minutes but that doesn't seem to freeze it yet.

Does anyone know if perhaps the waitforkey() could stop the processor from running after too long of a wait for example? Or do I maybe have some kind of memory leakage?

```
#include<Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 3;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'0', 'E', 'C'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8, 7, 6, 9};
byte colPins[COLS] = {2, 3, 4};
char command[4];
char p0;
char p1;
char p2;
char p3;
int count = 0;
int relayPin = 10;
bool solved = false;

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  keypad.setHoldTime(0);               // Default is 1000mS
  keypad.setDebounceTime(0);           // Default is 50mS
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  ledCompare(count);
  if (solved == true) {
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    command[3] = 'E';//makes statement untrue
    char key = keypad.waitForKey();
    count = 0;
    solved = false;
    ledsOff();
  }
  char key = keypad.waitForKey();
  if (key == 'C') {
    count = 0;
  }
  else {
    command[count] = key;
    count++;
  }
  if (count == 4) {
      if (command[0] == p0 && command[1] == p1 && command[2] == p2 && command[3] == p3) {
        solved = true;
      }
      else if(command[0] == p0 && command[1] == p1 && command[2] == p2 && command[3] == p3){
        reprogram();
      }
      else {
        ledsOff();
        digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
        solved = false;
        count = 0;
      }
    }
}

void ledsOn() {
  digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);//Meest rechter
  digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
}

void ledsOff() {
  digitalWrite(A0, LOW);//Meest rechter
  digitalWrite(A1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
}

void ledCompare(int x){
  if (count >= 1) {
    digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
  }
  if (count >= 2) {
    digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
  }
  if (count >= 3) {
    digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
  }
}

void reprogram(){
  ledsOff();
  char key = keypad.waitForKey();
  if(key != 'C'){
    p0 = key;
    digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    reprogram();
  }
  key = keypad.waitForKey();
  if(key != 'C'){
    p0 = key;
    digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    reprogram();
  }
  key = keypad.waitForKey();
  if(key != 'C'){
    p0 = key;
    digitalWrite(A1, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    reprogram();
  }
  key = keypad.waitForKey();
  if(key != 'C'){
    p0 = key;
    digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
    solved = true;
  }
  else{
    reprogram();
  }
}
```

Comment: Luckily, `reprogram()` is never called, no matter which values the undefined p1 , p2, p3  have.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely run out of memory due to your recursive reprogram() calls.

I don't even understand why you need recursive calls in the first place. Recursive calls are pretty much always a bad idea on a device with such limited memory.

Also see:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/355/how-much-can-i-recurse-how-much-can-i-recurse-how-much-caqfsdrfw

Comment: `reprogram();` should never be called, because of that silly `if (cond) {} else if (cond) { /* impossible to reach */ }`